# How large is the Meteor Snecko combo?

Tags: slay-the-spire

Suppose the board consists of the following cards and relics:

- 1x Meteor Strike+
- 2x Coolheaded+
- 1x Snecko Eye
- 1x Philosopher's Stone
- 1x Callipers
- (other relics less relevant)

While this seems like an infinite deck<sup>1</sup>, it actually is not, due to the 99 energy limit. It's a deck that deals a very large but finite amount of damage.
Assuming the player currently has:

- 4 energy
- 99 energy
- X energy (0 <= X < 99)

What is the currently expected amount of damage they would deal to an enemy with infinite health, assuming they play Meteor, Coolheaded, Coolheaded in a cycle?

Note: The answer isn't an infinite number because each cycle gives you 6 energy, but may consume anywhere from 0 to 9 energy. So if, 33 cycles in a row (99 cards in a row) you only roll 3's, then you run out of energy. The probability of that is 1 in [image: 1/3 ^ 99 = 1.72E47] If meteor strike gave out four orbs, then the expected damage, given P expected cycles, would thus be about [image: 33 x 30 x 1.72E47 ~ 1.70E50]. Of course, there are many other combinations as meteor strike gives you 3 orbs (6 energy): with a sufficient number of 3s you will run out of energy.

Markov chains could be useful to solve this problem.

<sup>1</sup>: It is assumed the enemy has 'Beat of Death' and thus you need to play two Coolheaded+ to generate enough Block.

<sup>2</sup>: When solved, this problem is useful to answer: How big does the Corrupt Heart need to be to give you a 50% chance of winning, if its damage limit is still 25% of its total hp? (slightly less than 17.5 times the expected damage).

Comment: This is not a complete answer, but I ran a short run of a simple model using a Python script (incomplete; I only considered e.g. the energy cost of one entire cycle, not of individual card plays). I assumed 4 starting energy. The resulting distribution of number of turns until running out of energy is *strongly* double-peaked; in 1000 trials, 730 went for >1000 turns (my per-run cutoff, for computation reasons), while 200 ended in <10 turns. The remainder were finished in less than 100 turns, strongly favoring fewer turns. Conclusion: ~73% of 4-energy starts will result in >30,000 damage.